# Navigation drawer slide over transparent background after update to material components 1.4.0

Tags: android, material-components-android

I was on an old version of material components, 1.0.0.  I am upgrading to 1.4.0, with I think 1.1.0 have most of the big style/theme changes.

I would like the navigation drawer to slide over the status bar.  I have this working with 1.0.0:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.Overflow</item>
</style>
```

However now with material 1.4.0 you have to set *android:statusBarColor* to a color.  So if I set:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/md_red_800</item>
```

Such that my status bar color is red, not the default purple, the drawer will no longer overlap the status bar on expand.

How can I set my status bar color and still have the drawer expand over the status bar?

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the Drawer doesn't slide *over* the status bar but *under* that.

You can set `windowTranslucentStatus` attribute to `true` in your `themes.xml` to get overlay state.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

However once you set it `true`, `statusBarColor` loses its effect. If you still want to have statusBar's background color, you have to set any color to its underlying background (ex. MainActivity's DrawerLayout) other than setting the color of statusBar itself. And you may also need to set `fitsSystemWindow` `true` to the content layout. Below is an example layout:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryVariant"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- contents here -->

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_view" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Seems like the colors are off, IE a material blue 600 is much darker.  Seems like the status bar is not 100% translucent.